# Rails Nested Forms Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, update-attributes

I'm having a problem getting update_attributes to update nested models in my form. I don't have any errors but the nested attributes aren't saving. Here's the relevant code:

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :orders
  has_many :achievements    

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :achievements
```

Achievements model:

```
class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Edit User form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

...

```
<%= f.fields_for :achievements do | a | %>
    <%= a.label :title %>
    <%= a.text_field :title %><br>
<% end  %>
```

Edit method:

```
def edit    
    @user = nil
    if params[:id] != nil
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
    elsif
      @user = current_user
    else
      redirect_to login_path
    end  
    5.times { @user.achievements.build }
  end
```

Update method:

```
@user.update_attributes params[:user]
```

But when I check the @user.achievements array it's always empty even when I fill out the forms. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :achievements_attributes`.  You can inspect the parameters for the form posts in your log file to see how rails named the form elements.  Or inspect the HTML on your page.

Comment: When I do that and try to load the page I get: "No association found for name `achievements_attributes'. Has it been defined yet?" Thoughts?

Comment: Whoops, I meant what you did for your answer `attr_accessible :achievements_attributes`.  I'm glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the user model:

```
attr_accessible :achievements_attributes
```

Seems to work :)